# how to deserialize JSON with keys that are not valid Python names in marshmallow

Tags: python, marshmallow

I'm getting a JSON object with a key `"sera:blah"`

How would I deserialize that object into a python data type using the marshmallow library as that colon is an invalid property name?

Edit:

So classes in python cannot accept a colon in the porperty name. It's invalid syntax.

Edit2:

Ideally I would like to have a workaround within marshmallow.

Comment: Perhaps you replace the colon with an underscore?

Comment: What happens when you try now? If you get an exception, including the stack trace and a minimal reproducer  would help folks who are curious start from the right place in the marshmallow library.

Comment: @sunnyPatel I can't it's IO data from an external call. I need to deserialize it into a class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see 2 routes you can take with this

- Try to deserialize it with [`JSON.loads`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html?highlight=json%20parse#json.loads) first, and iterate through each property and replace all the malformed keys before feeding it to marshmallow, or
- Use the [`JSON.JSONDecoder`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html?highlight=json%20parse#json.JSONDecoder) class and roll your own `object_hook` function. Then call the [`.decode()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html?highlight=json%20parse#json.JSONDecoder.decode) function before feeding it to marshmallow.

I've expanded on the latter (which I think is more appropriate)

```
from json import loads, JSONDecoder
s = """{
  "obj1": 123,
  "list": [
    {"example2": 42},
    {"sera:blah": false},
    {"object:3": {"nest:ed": "obj"}}
  ]
}"""

data = loads(s)
print(data)

def obj_transform(obj):
  for key in obj.keys():  # Iterate through obj
    if ':' in key:
      obj[key.replace(':', '_')] = obj.pop(key)
  return obj

decoder = JSONDecoder(object_hook=obj_transform)
print(decoder.decode(s))
```

The result of this prints:

> {'obj1': 123, 'list': [{'example2': 42}, {'sera:blah': False}, {'object:3': {'nest:ed': 'obj'}}]}
>   {'obj1': 123, 'list': [{'example2': 42}, {'sera_blah': False}, {'object_3': {'nest_ed': 'obj'}}]}

Which seems like what you are looking for, to sanitize your input to marshmallow.

Comment: Yeah a more concrete example will be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, this is not necessary. Marshmallow handles this neatly. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Marshmallow handles this with the `data_key` attribute.

```
class MySchema(ma.Schema):
    sara_blah = ma.fields.String(data_key="sara_blah")
```

(This is marshmallow 3 syntax. Marshmallow 2 used `load_from` and `dump_to`.)